# Bing Speech API send real time audio from microphone

Tags: api, bing, speech

I tried to Bing Speech API application.It will working fine in wave file detection  mode but how to read in microphone. If any sample program is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing Speech API now has support to read from Microphone, see Link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows